# "PLAIN login refused: User authentication failed" after upgrading RabbitMQ and Erlang

Tags: rabbitmq

I've just tryed upgrading my RabbitMQ from 3.9.8 to 3.9.14, as well as updating Erlang from 23.3 to 24.3.3 (*according to RabbitMQ documentation, RabbitMQ v3.9.14 supports Erlang from 23.2 to 24.x*), and unfortunately I'm experiencing some issues that I cannot find a solution to.

I have several consumers using the internal backend auth (username:password), and to authenticate to the management UI plugin, I'm using LDAP. That means that my config looks something like this:

```
[
    { rabbit, [
        {auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_ldap, rabbit_auth_backend_internal]}
    ]},
    ...
]
```

So I'm trying to authenticate using LDAP, if that doesn't work, RabbitMQ tries internal. This has been working ever since I installed RabbitMQ, but is not working anymore.

If I check the logs, it looks like is just fails to authenticate with LDAP, and it's as if it never tries with internal, which I cannot understand.

I've updated two of my 3 nodes in our production environment, so as of right now, all consumers and publishers are communicating with a single node. After updating our test environment, everything on test works as expected, so this is only an issue for my production environment.

I can't figure out was the issue is. I haven't touched anything within the config file.

What seems to be my issue?

**Snippet from log**

```
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0> ** Generic server <0.542.0> terminating
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0> ** Last message in was {submit,#Fun<rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.14.8489193>,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                <0.14152.0>,reuse}
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0> ** When Server state == {from,<0.14152.0>,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                               #Ref<0.4081940967.2306080769.101088>}
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0> ** Reason for termination ==
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0> ** {{case_clause,{ok,{eldap_search_result,[],[],asn1_NOVALUE}}},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     [{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,dn_lookup,2,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                [{file,"rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                 {line,826}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>      {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,call_ldap_fun,3,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                [{file,"rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                 {line,588}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>      {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,with_login,5,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                [{file,"rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                 {line,540}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>      {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,'-with_ldap/3-fun-2-',4,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                [{file,"rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                 {line,510}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>      {worker_pool_worker,handle_call,3,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                          [{file,"worker_pool_worker.erl"},{line,96}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>      {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"gen_server2.erl"},{line,1046}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>      {proc_lib,wake_up,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,236}]}]}
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0> 
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>   crasher:
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     initial call: worker_pool_worker:init/1
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     pid: <0.542.0>
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     registered_name: []
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     exception exit: {{case_clause,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                          {ok,{eldap_search_result,[],[],asn1_NOVALUE}}},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                      [{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,dn_lookup,2,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                           [{file,"rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},{line,826}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                       {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,call_ldap_fun,3,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                           [{file,"rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},{line,588}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                       {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,with_login,5,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                           [{file,"rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},{line,540}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                       {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,'-with_ldap/3-fun-2-',4,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                           [{file,"rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},{line,510}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                       {worker_pool_worker,handle_call,3,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                           [{file,"worker_pool_worker.erl"},{line,96}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                       {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                           [{file,"gen_server2.erl"},{line,1046}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                       {proc_lib,wake_up,3,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                           [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,236}]}]}
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>       in function  gen_server2:terminate/3 (gen_server2.erl, line 1183)
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     ancestors: [ldap_pool_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.241.0>]
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     message_queue_len: 0
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     messages: []
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     links: [<0.481.0>,<0.14130.0>]
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     dictionary: [{ldap_conns,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                       #{{false,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                             ["[DOMAIN OBSCURED]"],
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                             [{log,#Fun<rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.12.8489193>},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                              {port,389},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                              {idle_timeout,300000},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                              {anon_auth,false}]} =>
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                             <0.14130.0>}},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                   {worker_pool_worker,true},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                   {rand_seed,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                       {#{jump => #Fun<rand.3.92093067>,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                          max => 288230376151711743,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                          next => #Fun<rand.5.92093067>,type => exsplus},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                        [186383336712754926|245984873093678204]}},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                   {timeouts,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                       {dict,1,16,16,8,80,48,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                           {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                           {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                             [[{false,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                   ["[DOMAIN OBSCURED]"],
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                   [{log,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                        #Fun<rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.12.8489193>},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                    {port,389},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                    {idle_timeout,300000},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                                    {anon_auth,false}]}|
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                               #Ref<0.4081940967.2306080769.101090>]],
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                             [],[],[]}}}},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                   {worker_pool_name,ldap_pool},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                   {{parse_memo_table,rabbit_semver_parser},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>                    #Ref<0.4081940967.2306211841.100835>}]
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     trap_exit: false
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     status: running
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     heap_size: 1598
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     stack_size: 29
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     reductions: 194404
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>   neighbours:
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>     neighbour:
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>       pid: <0.14130.0>
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>       registered_name: []
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>       initial_call: {erlang,apply,2}
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>       current_function: {eldap,loop,2}
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>       ancestors: []
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>       message_queue_len: 0
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>       links: [<0.542.0>,#Port<0.1389>]
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>       trap_exit: false
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>       status: waiting
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>       heap_size: 6772
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>       stack_size: 6
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>       reductions: 93522
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.542.0>       current_stacktrace: [{eldap,loop,2,[{file,"eldap.erl"},{line,522}]}]
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>     supervisor: {local,ldap_pool_sup}
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>     errorContext: child_terminated
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>     reason: {{case_clause,{ok,{eldap_search_result,[],[],asn1_NOVALUE}}},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>              [{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,dn_lookup,2,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>                   [{file,"rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},{line,826}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>               {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,call_ldap_fun,3,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>                   [{file,"rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},{line,588}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>               {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,with_login,5,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>                   [{file,"rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},{line,540}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>               {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,'-with_ldap/3-fun-2-',4,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>                   [{file,"rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},{line,510}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>               {worker_pool_worker,handle_call,3,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>                   [{file,"worker_pool_worker.erl"},{line,96}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>               {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>                   [{file,"gen_server2.erl"},{line,1046}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>               {proc_lib,wake_up,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,236}]}]}
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>     offender: [{pid,<0.542.0>},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>                {id,60},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>                {mfargs,{worker_pool_worker,start_link,[ldap_pool]}},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>                {restart_type,transient},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>                {significant,false},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>                {shutdown,4294967295},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0>                {child_type,worker}]
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.481.0> 
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [info] <0.481.0> Supervisor {local,ldap_pool_sup}: child 60 started (<0.14153.0>): {worker_pool_worker,start_link,[ldap_pool]}
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0> User '[USERNAME OBSCURED]' authentication failed with exit:{{{case_clause,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                        {ok,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         {eldap_search_result,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                          [],[],asn1_NOVALUE}}},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                       [{rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         dn_lookup,2,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         [{file,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                           "rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                          {line,826}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                        {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         call_ldap_fun,3,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         [{file,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                           "rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                          {line,588}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                        {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         with_login,5,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         [{file,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                           "rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                          {line,540}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                        {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         '-with_ldap/3-fun-2-',
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         4,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         [{file,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                           "rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                          {line,510}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                        {worker_pool_worker,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         handle_call,3,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         [{file,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                           "worker_pool_worker.erl"},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                          {line,96}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                        {gen_server2,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         handle_msg,2,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         [{file,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                           "gen_server2.erl"},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                          {line,1046}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                        {proc_lib,wake_up,3,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                          {line,236}]}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                      {gen_server2,call,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                       [<0.542.0>,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                        {submit,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         #Fun<rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.14.8489193>,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                         <0.14152.0>,reuse},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                                                        infinity]}}:
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0> [{gen_server2,call,3,[{file,"gen_server2.erl"},{line,346}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>  {rabbit_auth_backend_ldap,user_login_authentication,2,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                            [{file,"rabbit_auth_backend_ldap.erl"},{line,71}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>  {rabbit_access_control,try_authenticate,3,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                         [{file,"rabbit_access_control.erl"},{line,92}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>  {rabbit_access_control,'-check_user_login/2-fun-0-',4,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                         [{file,"rabbit_access_control.erl"},{line,57}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>  {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1267}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>  {rabbit_access_control,check_user_login,2,
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>                         [{file,"rabbit_access_control.erl"},{line,42}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>  {rabbit_reader,auth_phase,2,[{file,"rabbit_reader.erl"},{line,1423}]},
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [debug] <0.14152.0>  {rabbit_reader,handle_method0,3,[{file,"rabbit_reader.erl"},{line,1133}]}]
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.14152.0> Error on AMQP connection <0.14152.0> ([IP OBSCURED]:61057 -> [IP OBSCURED]:5672, state: starting):
    2022-04-12 10:41:50.737000+02:00 [error] <0.14152.0> PLAIN login refused: User '[USERNAME OBSCURED]' authentication failed with internal error. Enable debug logs to see the real error.
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been fixed in 3.9.15:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/pull/4448

So an upgrade to a newer version should fix this